# How do I pass GHC options in Travis builds?

Tags: haskell, travis-ci

I'm getting a warning in my Travis CI build config validation for my Haskell project flagging `ghc-options` as an "unknown key":

> `jobs.include`: unknown key `ghc-options ({ $locals: -Wunsafe - ..., $ta ...)`

But I need to pass options to GHC, and have used this key in the past without issues (in fact I think I picked it up from Travis documentation). In my stack.yaml I have, for example:

```
jobs:
  include:
  #  [...]
  - name: "Stackage Nightly"
    env: RESOLVER=nightly 
    ghc-options:
      "$locals": -Wunsafe -Wunused-imports -Wdodgy-imports -Wdodgy-foreign-imports
      "$targets": -Wunsafe -Wunused-imports -Wdodgy-imports -Wdodgy-foreign-imports -Wall
  #  [...]
```

What is the (current) correct way to pass GHC options in Travis CI builds?

Comment: The consensus on github seems to be to `echo` it to the `cabal.project` file for cabal ([examples](https://github.com/search?q=filename%3A.travis.yml+ghc-options)), and for stack, to run `stack build --ghc-options` directly as a `script` ([examples](https://github.com/search?q=filename%3A.travis.yml+Wall+ghc+stack&type=Code)).